# Looking for right Car Park ambience...

Tags: ambience, samples, library-sound-effects

Hi,

Been searching for the right ambience for this scene and all my car park ambiences are too busy, or in the daytime, or just not right.

I'm wondering if anyone knows a sample library that has good car park ambiences, at night, without too much traffic.

(have a look at the picture to see what I mean)

[image]

Appreciate the advice.

Cheers,
Nicol

Comment: Delighted you guys are asking about sound effects on this site. It's beginning to feel like the old yahoo sound designer site that Randy Thom and others hung out on.  Anyway, I worked on I believe several movies with this sort of feel.  Would love to talk with you about what I can provide from my huge one of a kind lib.   My price depends on the budget of the project (and the niceness of the person asking:) if you really don't have too much of a budget. Sent you an email..at your website.  mine is: annk@soundmountain.com   

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Likely (and this may not be the answer you want to hear) you'll have to roll up your sleeves and build it.  It's the hallmark of good BGz actually, building from the ground up.  Finding some thick and dense air tones which create the right mood, a nice rumble, some HVAC tones and fluorescent buzzing, maybe OS alley drips if it's a wet scene, some OS tire skids and spotted car moves (including doors), maybe some OS walla here and there and spotted reverberant F/S bys.

I've actually recorded some rather empty garages and to be honest, they are incredibly boring sounding.

I can personally say that when posed with the exact situation you speak of, and show an example of, this is the approach I would take 100% of the time.  You never will find 1 or 2 sounds which work as-is for a BG.  It's all about breaking down what the scene calls for, not just literally but figuratively as well, and layering it together the right combination of elements to act as one cohesive environment.

Comment: Thanks ever so much for your tips. I think you're absolutely right, I will build this one from ground up.

Answer (score 6):

What @stavrosound said, plus it sounds like an excellent excuse for a late night recording session! rig mics etc so recorder can stay in your car, drive around carpark buildings, listening... and when you find a good quiet level, put the mic stand beside your car and hit record! Distant verby activity, even very sparsely will help sell the actuality if the location....

Comment: I'll be getting out there very soon! Deadline for this project is looming so it'll be for next time. Thanks hugely for your advice. 